# InvalidOperationException was unhandled 3

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba

I am on LogIn form in VB.Net. But I get an error when I'm trying to login. 
The error shows

> InvalidOperationException was unhandled

I am using a Microsoft Access database.

While I was run program it didn't say which line I had an error.
Please help me...I really appreciate you and very thankful in advance.

Below is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class login
Sub koneksi()
    conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\bin\Debug\db.accdb;Persist Security Info=True")
    conn.Open()
End Sub

Private Sub login_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    koneksi()
End Sub

Private Sub btnlogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
    If txtstaffid.Text = "" Or txtpassword.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please insert your staff ID and password")
        txtstaffid.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    Else
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("select * from user where staffid='" & Rep(txtstaffid.Text) & "' and pass='" & Rep(txtpassword.Text) & "'", conn)
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader          ' Error occurs here !!!
        rd.Read()
        If rd.HasRows Then
            MsgBox("Successful Login!")
            Me.Visible = False
            menuUtama.Show()
            menuUtama.Label1.Text = rd("role")
            Clear()
        Else
            MsgBox("Wrong staff ID or password")
            Clear()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Sub clear()
    txtstaffid.Text = ""
    txtpassword.Text = ""
End Sub
```

This is my `module1.vb`:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Module Module1

Public conn As OleDbConnection
Public cmd As OleDbCommand
Public rd As OleDbDataReader

Public Function Rep(ByVal kata As String) As String
    Rep = Replace(kata, "'", "''")
End Function
End Module
```

The error shows at the line

```
rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

Comment: There is a great deal wrong with that code.  I encourage you to stop and research those DB Provider tools before trying to work with them.  Also, storing passwords as plain text is a very bad idea

Comment: Have you tested that your connection is open? You should also test your SQL string to see what's actually in it before trying to use it